# sql скрипт на внесение изменений в одну из таблиц с учётом данных из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

начал потихоньку изучать sql и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно обновить данные в таблице "*bank account*" пересчитав их с учётом данных из таблицы "*transaction*". Я написал следующий скрипт: `update bank_account set current_balance  =  current_balance + money_operation from transaction where bank_account_id = bank_account.id;`, но он не проходит по таблице "*transaction*" до конца, а берёт только первые 3 значения и выдаёт следующий результат (см. "*bank account (result)*"). Есть ли способ дописать данный скрипт чтобы он охватывал всю таблицу "*transaction*"? Или может быть можно написать двойной цикл, чтобы он смотрел для каждого "*bank_account.id*" каждый "*transaction.bank_account_id*" и при совпадении пересчитывал?

bank account
[image: bank account]
transaction
[image: transaction]
bank account (result)
[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он не "берёт только первые 3 значения", а берёт по одному значению для каждого id.
Воспользуйтесь агрегатной функцией суммирования `sum`, которая вернёт сумму по всем записям для каждого id.

```
update bank_account
   set current_balance = current_balance + (select sum(money_operation)
                                              from transaction
                                             where bank_account_id = bank_account.id);
```

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо большое